# Trouble inserting a html image

Tags: html, insert, photo

I'm a complete novice and I only know HTML and JavaScript. For a few days I've been trying to get a picture inserted into a section of the site I am doing for my old school. I had done pretty much nothing when I got the problem. Basically, I've tried loads of photo hosting sites and the only one that worked was a very low-res one from the uniform manufacturer. Here is the code:

```html
<h3> Press one of the leaves to go to the desired area of the website. </h3>

<img src="https://imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/10/14/StHelensLogo.jpg" border="0">
```

Any help would be great! I've tried jpegs, pngs, ect and that one up there was just my latest try. Again, please bear with me... most people on this site are experts.

EDIT: Ignore the `<h> </h>` tags.

Edit: To clarify, I load the document in chrome or ie and the picture isn't there. When I give it an alt, I just see the alt. Also, the resolution is very high-something in the 4000's I think.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? The code you have included works, so its not clear what your question is. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46746331/edit) to describe what the expected behaviour is and what is not working, so we know what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm... The image is there, but it is enlarged quite a lot. I'm no expert, but you should definitely scale it down so you can see it easily. It is done by adding width and height after the url. Also images should be in .jpg format. The border does nothing to the image right now.

```
<h3> Press one of the leaves to go to the desired area of the website. </h3>

<img src="https://imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/10/14/StHelensLogo.jpg" width="25%" height="25%" />
```

Comment: Also, the ones that work are probably are small images.